# How late is too late? (aka getting "It is too late to undo this operation" while unstarring a chat message)

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

While unstarring a chat message I starred in the past, I got a message:

> [image: screen-shot]

So, I want to know: what is the time frame in which we can unstar the old message? In other words, After how much time it can't be undone, and why?

Answer (score 4):

OK, from own tests the answer is: 10 minutes since you last starred, regardless of the  message age.