# Trying to unstar a chat message starred more than ten minutes ago from the transcript fails silently

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-transcript

In a chat transcript, if I open the dropdown menu for a message I starred more than ten minutes ago ([the grace period for unstarring a message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269826/how-late-is-too-late-aka-getting-it-is-too-late-to-undo-this-operation-while)) and try to unstar it, the operation fails with no error message of any kind, e.g. "It is too late to undo this operation".

Can we get an error message when this happens, or better yet, not display the option to unstar the message in the dropdown altogether?

Comment: I didn't even know you could change stars in the transcript.